# Querying array and ignoring the order of the elements

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Consider a report that contains:

```
{
  "name": "n1",
  "version": "1.0",
  "ids": ["ABC", "XYZ"]
}
```

I want to find all reports that contain that name, version and ids. So I built:

```
.find({ "name": "n1", "version": "1.0", "ids": ["ABC", "XYZ"]})
```

But the problem is that I don't know the order of the elements in the ids array.  So the following query won't return reports:

```
.find({ "name": "n1", "version": "1.0", "ids": ["XYZ","ABC"]})
```

How can I tell the query to match if the array contains exactly does elements? Using MongoDB 3.2 and Pymongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine $size with $all, like so:

> **The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is**
>   **an array that contains all the specified elements**
>
> **The `$size` operator matches any array with the number of elements**
>   **specified by the argument**

```
{
  "cast": {
    $all: ['Peter Courtney', 'James J. Corbett'],
    $size : 2
  }
}
```

But be careful because it can be a very expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $all and $and operators, not the best and would need to determine size of array upfront

```
.find( { "name": "n1", "version": "1.0" , "ids" : { $all: ["XYZ","ABC"] }, "ids": { $size: 2 }})
```

I think this should work on 3.2.